# React Native, iOS, Google Signin redirects to google.com

Tags: react-native

React-Native-google-signin in ios redirects to google.com

AnyWay to resolve it?

using

react-native 0.55.4
react-native-google-signin 0.12.0
react 16.3.1

appdelegates.m looks like:

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {


  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                        openURL:url
                                              sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                     annotation:annotation
          ]
  || [RNGoogleSignin application:application
                         openURL:url
               sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                      annotation:annotation
      ];
}
```